# How to align drop down menu UL under parent LI?

Tags: css

So I'm adding a CSS drop down menu to a site however I am unable to get it to display properly.

The site in question is here > http://www.grimeforum.com/
When you hover over "news" LI, the child UL appears squashed.

I've spent the past few hours messing with positions but it either displays in the correct place but very squashed, or it floats to the left (but not squashed).

When I remove

```
position: relative;
```

from

```
#menu-nav li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
```

it appers unsquashed, but floated to the left outside of the parent LI.

Any ideas?

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sCW9A/
Remove postition:relative from line 463

Comment: For us to help diagnose your problem, please post the minimal ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) code (HTML and CSS) required to reproduce your problem *here*, and demos at a site where we can see, edit and amend the code in question, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) and others.

Comment: I checked on FF, and it looks fine to me. The Menu does some weird hover effect, but it drops down. Can you post what browser you are in.

Comment: For example, "Forthcoming Releases" is on two lines rather than one. Also, the hover effect is meant to be full background of the child LI rather than 3/4 of it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sCW9A/ Here is the fiddle.

Comment: OK, so removing the space between "Forthcoming Releases" made it look normal, so then I made it "Forthcoming&nbsp;Releases" and it still looked normal. How is the space affecting the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving it a width of 175px worked for me.

Okay I got the problem. Firstly change `#menu-nav li` to `#menu-nav>li` since you don't want all li's to float left under menu-nav
secondly add this to anchors under your submenu

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: I cant give it a static width as other items for other menus will be larger sized. I need to have it fluid widths.

Comment: Thanks, the first bit worked, but figured out the white-space trick moments before you posted this! I'll mark yours as the answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

the `a` element must be the one with `display: block` and `padding`.

```
#menu-nav ul li {
  padding: 0;
}

#menu-nav ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 180px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, learnt something new.

Added `white-space: nowrap;` to `#menu-nav ul li a{`and hey presto, no need for `&nbsp;` when using multiple word page titles, and no more layout issues.

Not really a fix but a workaround until I learn to code better I guess...!